# Cannot order to specific id

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to order the result for a specific `role_id` order, so:

```
$query = "SELECT p.*
FROM player_career cr
LEFT JOIN player p ON p.id = cr.player_id
WHERE team_id = :team_id AND season_id = :season_id
ORDER BY p.role_id (1, 2, 3, 4)";
```

I get:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION p.role_id does not exist
```

what is the mistake?

Comment: What do you mean by order for specific role order?

Comment: @KamilG. the table `player` have a field called `role_id`, this can assume the following values: 1, 2, 3, 4. So I want order the results to display first the record with role 1, later 2, then 3 and last 4...

Comment: Check my answer. You can have ascending and descending order. There's no need to specify these values.

Comment: what does `p.role_id (1, 2, 3, 4)` even mean???  I also don't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to call a function that doesn't exist `p.role_id (1, 2, 3, 4)`.  It's really hard to get a grasp on what (1,2,3,4) should do, the default order of `ORDER BY` is ascending though, so just omit the `(1,2,3,4)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort rows based on `role_id` simply use:

```
$query = "SELECT p.*
FROM player_career cr
LEFT JOIN player p ON p.id = cr.player_id
WHERE team_id = :team_id AND season_id = :season_id
ORDER BY p.role_id";
```

Default order behaviour is ascending so that `1` would sort before `2`. If you want to have the reverse output use descending order: `ORDER BY p.role_id DESC`.

If you need to filter role ids to get only these that you've specified as a condition apply it in `WHERE` but remember about `IN` operator:

```
WHERE team_id = :team_id AND season_id = :season_id AND p.role_id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

In SQL you call a function and specify it's parameters in parentheses which means that `p.role_id(...)` is going to be a function call.